# Lexical Tie-Ins with Flex and Bison

Tags: c, bison, lex, flex-lexer

I've been looking to recognise a language which does not fit the general Flex/Bison paradigm. It has completely different token rules depending on semantic context. For example:

```
main() {
    batchblock
    {
echo Hello World!
set batchvar=Something
echo %batchvar%
    }
}
```

Bison apparently supports recognition of these types of grammars, but it needs "[Lexical Tie Ins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lexical-Tie_002dins.html#Lexical-Tie_002dins)"  to support them effectively. It provides an interface for doing this -- but I'm confused as to how exactly I can supply different flex regexes depending on the context -- if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused as to how exactly I can supply different flex regexes depending on the context

Flex has a state mechanism whereby you can switch it between different sets of regexes. The syntax for this is

```
%x name_of_state
```

at the top of the file (after the `%}`) and in your matching rules (after the first `%%`)

```
<name_of_state> *regex goes here*
```

Then this regex is only matched when in that state. There is also a global state `<*>` which can be used to match anything in any state.

There is more than one way to change states. For example, `yy_pop_state` and `yy_push_state` if you want to keep a stack of states. Alternatively you can use `BEGIN(name_of_state)`. To go back to the initial state, use `BEGIN(INITIAL)`.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, specifically, if your special block is consistently signaled by 'batchblock {', this can be handled entirely inside of flex -- on the Bison (or byacc, if you want to make your life at least a little easier) side, you'd just see tokens that changed to something like 'BATCH_ECHO'.

To handle it inside of flex, you'd use its start conditions capability:

```
%x batchblock
%%

"batchblock"{ws}\{   { BEGIN(batchblock); }


<batchblock>echo     { return BATCH_ECHO; }
<batchblock>set      { return BATCH_SET;  }
/* ... */
<batchblock>\}       { begin(INITIAL);    }
```

The patterns that start with `<batchblock>` can only match in the "batchblock" state, which is entered by the `BEGIN(batchblock);`.

Comment: Here you need to put the `<batchblock>` between backticks otherwise it looks like 'The patterns that start with *""*'.

Comment: Thanks -- I believe I've got it fixed.